# apt-get and dpkg difference in file formats

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

If dpkg utility is used for installing .deb files what is the file extension for softwares that we install using apt-get.

Can we use apt-get also for .deb file formats ?

So in other words how do we make a decision on when to use apt-get and when to use dpkg for installing softwares.

Comment: see this https://superuser.com/questions/196864/how-to-install-local-deb-packages-with-apt-get

Comment: I am not clear on what the file format for a debian package would be . It cannot just be .deb file since in that case a dpkg would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

apt is a high-level front-end to dpkg, and dpkg is a front-end to dpkg-deb. So they all handle .deb archives, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Both dpkg and apt can be used for .deb files. dpkg and apt can both install and build or remove packages but dpkg provides a low-level package management as opposed to apt that is the high-level package management system. Therefore, dpkg does not install required other packages and check their dependencies.

You can use apt when you benefit its features regarding dependency checking and installing higher level capabilities.